# How do I read lines from a file in C?

Tags: c, file, null, malloc, fopen

I need to read in a file. The first line of the file is the number of lines in the file and it returns an array of strings, with the last element being a NULL indicating the end of the array.

```
char **read_file(char *fname)
{

    char **dict;

    printf("Reading %s\n", fname);
    FILE *d = fopen(fname, "r");
    if (! d) return NULL;

    // Get the number of lines in the file
    //the first line in the file is the number of lines, so I have to get 0th element
    char *size;
    fscanf(d, "%s[^\n]", size);
    int filesize = atoi(size);



    // Allocate memory for the array of character pointers
    dict = NULL;   // Change this

    // Read in the rest of the file, allocting memory for each string
    // as we go.

    // NULL termination. Last entry in the array should be NULL.

    printf("Done\n");

    return dict;
}
```

I put some comments because I know that's what I'm to do, but I can't seem to figure out how to put it in actual code.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you need to do one of two things.

1. Read the file as characters then convert to integers.
2. Read the file directly as integers.

For the first, you would use freed into a char array and then use atoi to convert to integer.

For the second, you would use fscanf and use the %d specify to read directly into an int variable;

fscanf does not allocate memory for you. Passing it a random pointer as you have will only cause trouble. (I recommend avoid fscanf).

Answer (score 0):

The question code has a flaw:

```
char *size;
fscanf(d, "%s[^\n]", size);
```

Although the above may compile, it will not function as expected at runtime.  The problem is that fscanf() needs the memory address of where to write the parsed value.  While `size` is a pointer that can store a memory address, it is uninitialized, and points to no specific memory in the process' memory map.

The following may be a better replacement:

```
fscanf(d, " %d%*c", &filesize);
```

*See my version of the spoiler code [here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23812742_how-do-i-read-lines-from-a-file-in-c.c)*